# Finding positon of an image onscreen via image matching

Tags: java, image, image-processing, pattern-matching, image-recognition

I'm currently trying to write a program in Java which will preform some macros however I need the macros to be capable of finding certain pictures located on my screen.

There is a function in Macro Schedule which is pretty much FindImagePos(myimage.bmp, tolerance(0-255)) and locates the image in about 0.2s at 1080P but the program would be a pain to code in Macro Scheduler.
The images are not distorted in any way except for slight color variations which is where tolerance comes in,

ex. finding this: http://min.us/idivEC.png in every one of these bars min.us/iR64a.png

I don't think I could code such a function efficiently and briefly skimmed ImageJ and Neuroph which seemed complicated and overkill and would like to know if there was something simpler.

The only theory on how to code this would be to take screenshot, convert it into a 2D RGB array, search the rows for the occurrence of the first row in the sample image with some leniency (aka tolerance) and if it matches up somewhat then check underneath the row for the second row and so on.

Comment: damn... Can't remember the name: but there's an excellent API used by a GUI-testing tool that does just that.  It allows for tolerance etc. but I can't remember the name now: in the GUI-testing framework, you can write code like "wait 3 seconds, then click on the button that looks likes '...'" and the code shall work on Linux, OS X and Windows etc, despite the slight font rendering difference.  Sadly I can't come up with the name right now... Will comment back if I do.

Comment: @Webinator: Didn't you mean Abbot? http://abbot.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What I mean by tolerance is that if the image onscreen is slightly different in color then it should still be found depending on what tolerance I set it to.